# How to get multiple <td> text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I get the text for the first td that is created by this loop using jQuery?

Assuming this code makes 14 rows:

```
@foreach (string item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td id="td_name" style="border-left: thin">@item</td>                
        <td><input type="text" id="txtGrade_@item" onclick="" style="width: 40px;border-left: thin"/></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkStudent_@item" value="@item" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: jQuery offers a function for this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Not sure what you're asking: `$("td").first().text()` ?

Comment: i can get the text for that specific td if the model only has 1 records in it. but what if i contains more?

Comment: Do you want the first or do you want all of them? Your question isn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `.eq()` method to select the desired element providing it's index, and `.text()` method to get it's text.

---

Check the example:

```js
function getFirstCellTextList(tableElement) {
   if (tableElement instanceof jQuery) {
      // Create an array
      var textList = [];

      // Iterate over each table row
      tableElement.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
          // Get the first cells's text and push it inside the array
          var row = $(this);
          if (row.children('td').length > 0) {
             textList.push(row.children('td').eq(0).text());
          }                  
      });
      return textList;
   }
}

// Get the array
var myList = getFirstCellTextList($('#your_table'));

alert(myList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="your_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Senond</th>
    <th>Third</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>First cell 1</td><td>Second cell 1</td><td>Third cell 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First cell 2</td><td>Second cell 2</td><td>Third cell 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First cell 3</td><td>Second cell 3</td><td>Third cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First cell 4</td><td>Second cell 4</td><td>Third cell 4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you. it works. but it also get a null value for the first record it gets. is it because of the <th> that i have in my table? if that is the reason. is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: It is recommended that you separate the heading from the body. Put the th elements inside a <thead> and the table body rows inside a <tbody>. Otherwise, on each iteration, check that there is a <td> element inside the row.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$('td:first')` will get you the first td in the document. you can then use the `text()` to get the text or `this.$('td:first')[0].innerHTML` to get the HTML under `td`